# Unable to edit my "Administration Email Address" after mySQL editing?

Tags: admin

WordPress won't let me change my administration email address.

I've checked the spam folder and what's more I even changed the email in the mySQL and it still shows up...

Any idea how to kill off this error?

I took the advice of the below advice to find the following in the DB:

```
update wp_options set option_value='you@example.com' where option_name='admin_email' ;
```

I changed the above, saved it, and here's the evidence:

I had to cut off the email address after @ but you get the idea...

This is strange right?

Any other course of action I can take?

I tried clearing cache...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the setting in General Settings > Administration Email Address, that comes from the `admin_email` value in the `wp_options` table. Change that with e.g.:

```
update wp_options set option_value='you@example.com' where option_name='admin_email' ;
```

Comment: Thanks @mozboz I did what you said, great advice, but alas - oddly, it didn't work..